# Search or Filter in a dynamic checkbox list control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
const filterEl = document.querySelector('#filter');
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#mdi > span'));
const labels = els.map(el => el.textContent);
const handler = value => {
  const matching = labels.map((label, idx, arr) => label.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ? idx : null).filter(el => el != null);

  els.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (matching.includes(idx)) {
      els[idx].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      els[idx].style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};

filterEl.addEventListener('keyup', () => handler.call(null, filterEl.value));


const filterEl2 = document.querySelector('#filter1');
const elss = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#mdii > span'));
const labelss = elss.map(el => el.textContent);
const handlerr = value => {
  const matching = labelss.map((label, idx, arr) => label.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ? idx : null).filter(el => el != null);

  elss.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (matching.includes(idx)) {
      elss[idx].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      elss[idx].style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};

filterEl2.addEventListener('keyup', () => handlerr.call(null, filterEl2.value));
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

#mdi {
border:1px solid #ccc;
height:100px;
overflow-y:scroll;
width:250px;
background:#ccc;
border-radius:5px;
padding:5px;
}
#mdii {
border:1px solid #ccc;
height:100px;
overflow-y:scroll;
width:250px;
background:#ccc;
border-radius:5px;
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<label for="filter">Filter record&nbsp;</label><input id="filter" type="text" class="filter">
<br/><br/>
<div id="mdi">
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="616">Child care</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="615">Counseling</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="612">Percursion</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="611">Playing drums</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="610">Playing guitar</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="609">Playing Piano</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="613">Sound equipment </span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="614">Ushering</span>
</div>

<br>

<label for="filter1">Filter record&nbsp;</label><input id="filter1" type="text" class="filter">
<br/><br/>
<div id="mdii">
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="616">Home pomade</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="615">Comb</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="612">Sticker</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="611">Drums</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="610">Playing guitar</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="609">Playing Piano</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="613">Sound equipment </span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="614">Ushering</span>
</div>
```

I have a checkbox list control i built dynamically but i want to filter for values on key up when  the a value is entered into the search input filed

```
<!-- search box -->
<input type="text" class="filter" title="Filter record">


<!-- div to search in -->

<div id="mdi" style="width:250px;" class="talents_idmd">
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="616"><span id="talents_idspantext">Child care</span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="615">
<span id="talents_idspantext">Counseling</span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="612"><span id="talents_idspantext">Percursion</span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="611"><span id="talents_idspantext">Playing drums</span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="610"><span id="talents_idspantext">Playing guitar</span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="609"><span id="talents_idspantext">Playing Piano</span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="613"><span id="talents_idspantext">Sound equipment </span>
<br>
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="614"><span id="talents_idspantext">Ushering</span>
<br>
</div>
```

The required result is that,say if **child care** is entered in to the search box with the class name **filter** the div should show only

```
<input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="616"><span id="talents_idspantext">Child care</span>
<br>
```

and since i dynamically generate the div control with the search on top of each the **this** keyword should be used to allow for search on the current object and not all. Thanks

i tried

```
 $('.filter').on("keyup",function(){
      var txt = $(this).val(); 
       $('.<?php echo $appendClass;?>md-checkbox,#<?php echo $appendClass;?>spantext').hide();
        $('.<?php echo $appendClass;?>md-checkbox,#<?php echo $appendClass;?>spantext').each(function(){
         if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
             $(this).show();
         }
      });
  });
```

using jquery were  $appendClass is a dynamic name so that if i have multiple of such control on the page they will all have unique class names

Comment: You have to put **your code in the question**.

Comment: i have just done that please

Comment: If you dynamically created these checkboxes, does this mean you have JSON from which they were generated? Where I'm going with this: you could convert the JSON to an array and remove html elements based upon array searches.

Comment: yeah it was generated from a json string coming from a db

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the checkboxes to display only ones that match the user input filter. You could achieve that with what you have by doing something like below. I also removed some of the HTML that seemed incorrect or unnecessary.

```js
const filterEl = document.querySelector('#filter');
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#mdi > span'));
const labels = els.map(el => el.textContent);
const handler = value => {
  const matching = labels.map((label, idx, arr) => label.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ? idx : null).filter(el => el != null);

  els.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (matching.includes(idx)) {
      els[idx].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      els[idx].style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};

filterEl.addEventListener('keyup', () => handler.call(null, filterEl.value));
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="filter">Filter record&nbsp;</label><input id="filter" type="text" class="filter">
<br/><br/>
<div id="mdi">
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="616">Child care</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="615">Counseling</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="612">Percursion</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="611">Playing drums</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" value="610">Playing guitar</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="609">Playing Piano</span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="613">Sound equipment </span>
  <span><input class="talents_idmd-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="614">Ushering</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Tom O. the code snippet you provided work great but to add to what i was looking for ,if i have multiple of such divs with the filter on top of each how do i get it to work for each separately

Comment: Hi  guys  please i would like to seek improvement on the code above so that each checkbox list will filter by the **filter record**  input field above it using the same javascript base code,thus the javascript code  will be in a form of an object